# Self hosted Web Analaytics like urchin

Tags: iis, web-server, analytics

I would like some cheap/free web analytic software to be used on my windows server (Server 2008). urchin seems to be way expensive.  please provide me some good recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Piwik](http://piwik.org/) seems being worth a try. But all information I gathered told me that it isn't as complete as urchin - but I think this is nothing to wonder about.

Since the question is not directly related with server-administration it might be a good idea to check over at [webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).